# Set property in draw time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How I can set text to circles when I draw them? and how I can change some of property in redraw them?

```
<div id="ways" style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;height:100%;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

this is my code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testtest/8v1ksLjy/)

Comment: Do you want to change the text that is displayed?

Comment: No, I want when draw a circle, for set text to it from a array,How I can do this?